# Use array for R.drawable' address (java)

Tags: java, android, arrays

Tell me please how to write a path to a folder "R.drawable" with an array? For example, to the folder of the app I write the path this way:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21;) {
    pic[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/data/data/app.myapp/pic" + Integer.toString(i) + ".png")
}
```

But how can I get Bitmaps with name pic1, pic2, pic3 etc from the folder R.drawable? This is not right:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 21;) {
    picBitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameContext.getResources(), R.drawable.pic[i]); 
}
```

Comment: asked bazillion times, solutions: 1) make an int array of drawable ids or 2) use function which returns resorce id for resource name

Answer (score 1):

Create an integer Array

```
int d[] = {R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, ..}

for (int i=0; i<d.length(); i++) {
        picBitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameContext.getResources(), d[i]); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `i` is never updated, so you will have a infinite loop. Also you must create an `int[]` array to store `drawables`.

```
int[] drawables = {R.drawable.pic1, R.drawable.pic2, ..}


for (int i=0; i<21; i++) {
//                  ↑ you should update i!!!
    picBitmap[i] = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(gameContext.getResources(), drawables [i]);  
}
```

Also I would recommend to use `length` attribute of the `picBitmap` array:

```
for (int i=0; i<picBitmap.length; i++) {
```

Comment: but the syntax is wrong for Android. you can never get the drawable by `R.drawable.pic[i]`

Comment: ok, thanks! about "i++" - it was typo, of course I know about it ))

Comment: @RomanMartynov it's not necessary a typo, you can avoid the `i++` in a for loop if you update `i` later or also if you want to break the loop after a condition, `java` allows it and is really useful and improves readability lot of times i:e:  `for (int = 0;; i++)` is valid like your `for(int i=0; i<21;)`... you only have to break the loop or update counter somewhere to avoid infinite iterations ;)